# Is there a Kriegspiel android app?

Tags: chess-variants

I'm looking for an android app for a variant of chess which is called Kriegspiel. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriegspiel_(chess))

I don't expect any PvP app but I'd satisfied with PvC app. (OK; I know it's harder to make PvC)

And if somebody knows fairly good computer software for Kriegspiel please recommend it to me. I know one software, http://www.kriegspiel.co.uk/ but just in case if there is a better software.

Answer (score 2):

There is an app called Dark Chess:
[Dark Chess for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onecwireless.darkchess.google.free)

I know it's not exactly the variation you asked for, but I thought it could be useful in some way.

Comment: Moreover, just in case, there is also the full (paid) version of that app.